# Pivot table with multiple aggfunc sum and normalize one column

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have a pivot table. I can't find solution how to add two agg func: sum and percent (proportion to total sum)

```
table = pd.pivot_table(natnl_valyuta, values='vsego_zadoljennost', index=['koridor_procent'],
                columns=['yur_fiz', 'srok'], aggfunc=np.sum, margins= True)
```

[result of pivot table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzwSE.png)

I have to calculate also proportion to total sum as percentages

[expected output table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mb8a3.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my tests I created the following "surrogate" DataFrame:

```
txt = ''',FL,FL,YUL,YUL
,1-Kpatk,3-Dolg,1-Kpatk,3-Dolg
0-5,            0,  469532,       0, 3421599
10-15,          2,  342485,    3394, 1084686
16-20,        349,  419492,  131095, 1578722
20 i bolee, 33941,  482238,  167077,  343972
6-10,         309, 1688537,   16479,  486425'''
table = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(txt), header=[0,1], skipinitialspace=True,
    index_col=0, dtype={0:'object'})
table['All'] = table.sum(axis=1)
table.index.name = 'koridor_procent'
table.columns.set_names(['yur_fiz', 'srok'],inplace=True)
table = table.append(table.sum(axis=0).rename('All'))
```

Create it, print and check whether it is just the same as the result of
your *pivot_table*.

Your task can be performed in the following steps:

1. To have proper order of rows, create a *Categorical* index and reindex the table with it:

   ```
   cats = ['0-5', '6-10', '10-15', '16-20', '20 i bolee', 'All']
   table = table.reindex(pd.CategoricalIndex(cats, categories=cats).rename(table.index.name))
   ```
2. Reorder columns by the top level of the column index:

   ```
   table = table.sort_index(axis=1, level=1, ascending=False)
   table = table.reindex(['YUL', 'FL', 'All'], level=0, axis=1)
   ```
3. Generate percentage columns:

   ```
   pctCols = []
   for colName, col in table.iteritems():
       if colName[0] != 'All':
           pctCol = (col / col.iloc[-1] * 100).round(1).astype('str') + '%'
           pctCol.name = (colName[0], 'dola')
           pctCols.append(pctCol)
   ```
4. Inset percentage columns:

   ```
   pos = 1
   for col in pctCols:
       table.insert(pos, column=col.name, value=col, allow_duplicates=True)
       pos += 2
   ```

For the above test data, I got the following result:

```
yur_fiz              YUL                               FL                               All
srok              3-Dolg    dola 1-Kpatk    dola   3-Dolg    dola 1-Kpatk    dola           
koridor_procent                                                                             
0-5              3421599   49.5%       0    0.0%   469532   13.8%       0    0.0%   3891131 
6-10              486425    7.0%   16479    5.2%  1688537   49.6%     309    0.9%   2191750 
10-15            1084686   15.7%    3394    1.1%   342485   10.1%       2    0.0%   1430567 
16-20            1578722   22.8%  131095   41.2%   419492   12.3%     349    1.0%   2129658 
20 i bolee        343972    5.0%  167077   52.5%   482238   14.2%   33941   98.1%   1027228 
All              6915404  100.0%  318045  100.0%  3402284  100.0%   34601  100.0%  10670334
```