# Using agg with multi index in pandas

Tags: pandas, multi-index

I have a multi index table in pandas that is divided by columns, like in the example below:

```
import pandas as pd
header = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['loc1','loc2'],
                                     ['S1','S2']],
                                    names=['loc','S'])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, high=5, size=(5,4)), 
                  index=['a','b','c','d','e'], 
                  columns=header)
print(df)
```

with output:

```
loc loc1    loc2   
S     S1 S2   S1 S2
a      4  2    2  5
b      1  4    2  4
c      2  4    2  3
d      3  4    1  2
e      4  1    3  1
```

I'm trying to perform actions on "loc1" and "loc2", for which I use

```
df.agg({'loc1':sum, 'loc2':np.mean})
```

but I'm getting an error:
"SpecificationError: nested renamer is not supported".

The expected output is a row with the sum of (loc1, S1) and (loc1, S2), 
and the mean of (loc2, S1) and (loc2, S2),in my case

```
  loc1    loc2  
  sum     mean    
  S1 S2   S1 S2  
  14 15    2  3
```

How can I do this calculation with the "agg" function?
Is there any work around?

p.s. I know I can do it like in the answer [Pivot table with multiple aggfunc sum and normalize one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60089229/pivot-table-with-multiple-aggfunc-sum-and-normalize-one-column), 
but it seems somehow "non-pythonic".

Answer (score 3):

You can use dictionaty comprehension with [`DataFrame.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) and [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), last [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) for `MultiIndex Series` with [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) and transpose for one row `DataFrame`:

```
d = {'loc1':'sum','loc2':'mean'}

df1 = pd.concat({k: df[k].agg([v]).stack() for k, v in d.items()}).to_frame().T
print (df1)
  loc1       loc2     
    sum       mean     
     S1    S2   S1   S2
0  15.0  14.0  2.6  2.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately support for `agg` on columns (axis=1) is not not as complete as for rows. The solution is to do it in two `agg` calls.

Create the aggregates

```
o1 = df['loc1'].agg('sum').rename('sum').to_frame()
o2 = df['loc2'].agg('mean').rename('mean').to_frame()
```

Combine the aggregates

```
result = pd.concat([o1,o2],axis=1, keys=['loc1', 'loc2'])
```

Finally do some wrangling to get the data into the required format

```
result = result.unstack().to_frame().T
```

Result

```
  loc1       loc2     
   sum       mean     
S   S1    S2   S1   S2
0  9.0  10.0  2.4  2.4
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to the sum over each row per `loc`. We need to specify a `level` and `axis` in our groupby:

```
df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).sum(axis=1)

loc      loc1      loc2
a   -0.159510  0.669699
b    0.406272  2.258626
c   -0.703832  0.274719
d   -1.453601 -0.480166
e    1.128587  0.504887
```

To assign it back, we can use `join`, since the indices stay the same:

```
dfn = df.join(df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).sum(axis=1))

   (loc1, S1)  (loc1, S2)  (loc2, S1)  (loc2, S2)      loc1      loc2
a   -0.540104    0.380594    0.591548    0.078151 -0.159510  0.669699
b   -0.161479    0.567751    1.392222    0.866404  0.406272  2.258626
c   -0.549657   -0.154175    0.447627   -0.172908 -0.703832  0.274719
d   -1.811309    0.357709    0.124907   -0.605073 -1.453601 -0.480166
e    2.274189   -1.145603    0.458101    0.046786  1.128587  0.504887
```

Note that your MultiIndex columns got flattened.

To keep your MultiIndex levels, we have to create an artificial level called `sum`:

```
dfg = df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).sum(axis=1)
dfg.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([dfg.columns, ['sum']])

dfn = df.join(dfg)

loc      loc1                loc2                loc1      loc2
S          S1        S2        S1        S2       sum       sum
a   -0.540104  0.380594  0.591548  0.078151 -0.159510  0.669699
b   -0.161479  0.567751  1.392222  0.866404  0.406272  2.258626
c   -0.549657 -0.154175  0.447627 -0.172908 -0.703832  0.274719
d   -1.811309  0.357709  0.124907 -0.605073 -1.453601 -0.480166
e    2.274189 -1.145603  0.458101  0.046786  1.128587  0.504887
```

Finally, if you want so sort your columns by `loc`, use `sort_index`:

```
dfn.sort_index(axis=1)

loc      loc1                          loc2                    
S          S1        S2       sum        S1        S2       sum
a   -0.540104  0.380594 -0.159510  0.591548  0.078151  0.669699
b   -0.161479  0.567751  0.406272  1.392222  0.866404  2.258626
c   -0.549657 -0.154175 -0.703832  0.447627 -0.172908  0.274719
d   -1.811309  0.357709 -1.453601  0.124907 -0.605073 -0.480166
e    2.274189 -1.145603  1.128587  0.458101  0.046786  0.504887
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm using different actions and perform it on columns, that's why I needed the "agg" method. See the edit for the description.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it appears that dataframes with pd.MultiIndex and using dictionary in agg is not supported, however, here is a work around that will generate your desired ouput.

```
df_sum = df.agg('sum')[['loc1']].rename('sum').to_frame().stack().reorder_levels([0,2,1])
df_avg = df.agg('mean')[['loc2']].rename('mean').to_frame().stack().reorder_levels([0,2,1])
pd.concat([df_sum, df_avg]).to_frame().T
```

Output:

```
loc  loc1       loc2     
      sum       mean     
S      S1    S2   S1   S2
0    11.0  15.0  3.4  2.6
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to achieve your desired output. One of an indirect way is using dict comprehension to construct an agg dictionary. After that, using this dictionary to `agg` and  switching around columns and indices to get the desired output:

```
ops_dict = {'loc1':'sum', 'loc2':'mean'}
agg_dict = {(x,y): [ops_dict[x]] for x,y in df.columns}
df_agg = df.agg(agg_dict).stack([0,1]).swaplevel(0,1).sort_index(0).to_frame().T

Out[65]:
   loc1       loc2
    sum       mean
     S1    S2   S1   S2
0  14.0  15.0  2.0  3.0
```

---

Or use `pd.concat` with parameter `keys` on direct `sum` and `mean` of each `locX`

```
df_agg = pd.concat([df[['loc1']].sum(), df[['loc2']].mean()], 
                   keys=['sum','mean']).swaplevel(0,1).to_frame().T
```

or

```
df_agg = pd.concat([df['loc1'].sum(), df['loc2'].mean()], 
                   keys=[('loc1','sum'), ('loc2','mean')]).to_frame().T

Out[67]:
loc  loc1       loc2
      sum       mean
S      S1    S2   S1   S2
0    14.0  15.0  2.0  3.0
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do

```
new_df = (df.stack('S')
            .groupby(level='S')
            .agg(loc1_sum = ('loc1', 'sum'), loc2_mean = ('loc2', 'mean')))
print(new_df)
    loc1_sum  loc2_mean
S                      
S1        11        2.0
S2        10        1.8
```

---

```
new_df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(map(tuple, new_df.columns.str.split('_')))
result = new_df.unstack().to_frame().T
print(result)

   loc1       loc2     
    sum       mean     
S    S1    S2   S1   S2
0  11.0  10.0  2.0  1.8
```